# Passing Json Array's object is array to WCF

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a WCF Service.  Interface has class which contains List.

```
[DataContract]
    public class MainClass
    {
    [DataMember]
        public List<ItemClass> JsonArray
        { get; set; }

}
[DataContract]
    public class ItemClass
    {
[DataMember]
        public List<ItemListClass> JsonListArray
        { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
    public class ItemListClass
    {
[DataMember]
        public InnerItem
        { get; set; }

}
```

I want to save a List of data. Eg: JsonList  has 3 Items.  I added Json values  as

```
For(var i=0;i<ListFromDB;i++){
JsonList [(JsonList  .length)]={
Item : ListFromDB[i].Value //( List contains Vegetables,Fruits and Sweets.)
}
}
```

Each Item of JsonList has List. That is saved as

```
For(var i=0;i<ListforItem;i++){
JsonitemList [(JsonitemList.length)]={
Item : JsonitemList [i].item //( this List contains Tomato,chilli for vegetables, Mango,Orange,Banana for Fruits etc.)
}
}
```

I have a function that calls WCF.

```
Function SaveItems()
{
var dXmlhttp;


    var colUrl = LocalHost + "/ItemService.svc/json/additems";
    var columnData = {
        "objitem": {

            " JsonArray ": JsonList,
            // here I need to pass JsonList’s array . that is JsonitemList.

        }
    };
    var parmColum = JSON.stringify(columnData);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        colHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        colHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    colHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (colHttp.readyState == 4 && colHttp.status == 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(colHttp.responseText);
            //DisplayQCList(hdnfrom.value, hdnto.value, selectedvalue);

Alert(‘Success’);
        }
    }
    colHttp.open("POST", colUrl, true);
    colHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    colHttp.send(parmColum);

}
```

How  to pass JsonList’s array object to WCF( here JsonitemList.)